# How to ask someone to send me a shipment using regular mail instead of courier mail?

Tags: буквы

I have a Russian artist friend who speaks terrible English and I speak terrible Russian. He's sending me this amulet that he made which is small enough to fit in an envelope. How do I explain to him to send it to me using regular mail in an envelope instead of courier mail (ups, fedex, dhl). I'm not able to receive packages I have to sign for here.

Comment: regular mail=обычная почта (`Пошли мне обычной почтой`)

Comment: @Jacob: could you please make it an answer?

Comment: As a side note, In Russia, the regular post is _extremely_ unreliable.  There are also limitation as to what can be sent in an envelope (as opposed to a small box).  It's been a while since I checked, but back then only papers could be sent in an envelope.  For something as valuable as a hand-made amulet I would most certainly advise using a courier.

Comment: @AleksG, despite this stereotype, I've been using the regular postal service for almost 3 years when getting goods from eBay, and it always delivers packages (even with valuable items) without any loss or damage, quite slow though. However, if some issue happens with a package, I guess it would be pretty difficult to get any satisfaction from the postal staff.

Comment: @Ivan Fair point.  I haven't used Russian post in many years. BTW, what city is it in?  This varies drastically across geographies.

Comment: @AleksG, I'm in Novosibirsk

Answer (score 1):

Courier mail is "курьерская доставка", regular mail - "обычная почта". In envelope -"в конверте".

And "I'm not able to receive packages I have to sign for here" can be said like "Я не могу у себя получать посылки, за которые нужно ставить подпись".

Comment: ...  за которые надо расписываться

Answer (score 0):

To make it a polite request, you can write something like this: "Пожалуйста, вышлите мне товар обычной почтой в обычном конверте. Заказное письмо или курьерская почта предполагает подпись получателя, а это невозможно в моем случае. Спасибо!"

Which translates as: "Please, send shipment using regular mail in regular envelope. Registered mail or Courier mail service would require a signature of the recipient which is impossible in my case. Thank you!"